# mocking API module is not resolved with mocked data

Tags: jestjs

I have a strange issue with mocking an async/await function. Well, I have a simple api.js file which uses the fetch call to get some data. I'm trying to mock this call but with no luck so far

**api.js**

```
export async function getUsers() {
    const resp = await fetch(`/users`);
    const data = await resp.json();
    return data.message;
}
```

**__mock__/api.js**

```
const users = [
    "Jhon",
    "Paul",
    "Ringo"
];

export default function getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        process.nextTick(() => {
            resolve(users)
        });
    });
}
```

**api.test.js**

```
jest.mock('./api');
import {getUsers} from "./api";

test("user list is an array", async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const resp = await getUsers();
    expect(Array.isArray(resp)).toBe(true);
});
```

but I keep getting an undefined response.

Comment: Did your figure this out? I have a similar issue

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export function getUsers()` and not `export default function getUsers()` in your `__mock__/api.js` ??

Answer (score 0):

You need change `export` to `export default` for `api.js`:

`api.js`:

```js
export default async function getUsers() {
  const resp = await fetch(`/users`);
  const data = await resp.json();
  return data.message;
}
```

`__mocks__/api.js`:

```js
const users = ['Jhon', 'Paul', 'Ringo'];

export default function getUsers() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      resolve(users);
    });
  });
}
```

Unit test:

`api.test.js`:

```js
import getUsers from './api';

jest.mock('./api');

test('user list is an array', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const resp = await getUsers();
  expect(Array.isArray(resp)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Unit test result:

```js
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47531051/api.test.ts
  ✓ user list is an array (8ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.852s
```